# Bubble sort index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

```
Public Class Form3
Public Swapped As Boolean
Public ComparisonNumber As Integer
Dim Temp As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Swapped = True
    While Swapped = True
        Swapped = False
        ComparisonNumber = 0
        While ComparisonNumber < PatientCount
            If Names(ComparisonNumber) > Names(ComparisonNumber + 1) Then
                Temp = Names(ComparisonNumber)
                Names(ComparisonNumber) = Names(ComparisonNumber + 1)
                Names(ComparisonNumber + 1) = Temp
                Swapped = True
            End If
            ComparisonNumber = ComparisonNumber + 1
        End While
    End While

    For i = 0 To PatientCount
        lstPatientNames.Items.Add(Names(i))
        lstPatientHeights.Items.Add(Heights(i))
        lstPatientWeights.Items.Add(Weights(i))
    Next

End Sub
End Class
```

This is the code for my bubble sort for a project but when I press the button that sorts and displays the array I get the error: **`"index was outside the bounds of the array"`** on the line

```
If Names(ComparisonNumber) > Names(ComparisonNumber + 1) Then
```

Any ideas as to why?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `PatientCount` is the number of items being stored in `Names` (you've not shown the definition for either of these) then the indexes for `Names` run from 0 to `PatientCount - 1`.

So, in the last iteration, when `ComparisonNumber` is *equal* to `PatientCount - 1`, you attempt to access the items at indexes `PatientCount - 1` and `PatientCount` - but that second index is invalid.

```
Swapped = True
While Swapped = True
    Swapped = False
    ComparisonNumber = 0
    While ComparisonNumber < PatientCount - 1 'Changed here
        If Names(ComparisonNumber) > Names(ComparisonNumber + 1) Then
            Temp = Names(ComparisonNumber)
            Names(ComparisonNumber) = Names(ComparisonNumber + 1)
            Names(ComparisonNumber + 1) = Temp
            Swapped = True
        End If
        ComparisonNumber = ComparisonNumber + 1
    End While
End While

For i = 0 To PatientCount - 1 'And here
    lstPatientNames.Items.Add(Names(i))
    lstPatientHeights.Items.Add(Heights(i))
    lstPatientWeights.Items.Add(Weights(i))
Next
```

Also, these lines seem wrong:

```
    lstPatientHeights.Items.Add(Heights(i))
    lstPatientWeights.Items.Add(Weights(i))
```

Because you haven't been sorting `Heights` and `Weights` in the same way that you have been sorting `Names`, so they're going to still be in their original order. You either should be performing the same swaps to all of these when you decide to perform a swap, or you ought to be storing objects in a single (array?) that have 3 properties - `Name`, `Height` and `Weight` and then be swapping these objects.

Comment: So how would I go about storing the Heights and Weights in the same array?

Comment: is there any way to store the hiehgts and weights in the same array?

Comment: @Marcel - you could create a [`Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/527aztek.aspx) with 3 `Properties` - Name, Height and Weight, with whatever data type your currently storing in your array for those items. Then store objects of this class in your array.